# HTML element to display text, but not from direct user input

Tags: html, text, display

Learning HTML, but can't find this:  An element that displays text, but not initially (at the outset it's blank), and not from direct user input. User clicks a button (not this element) which causes the program to select an item, randomly, from a list (or array), and display that text item in this element. Click the button again and another text item is randomly selected and displayed. Or the current item is deleted, leaving this element blank.

Comment: What have you tried already? Can you put a code sample into your question that shows your work thus far?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 1):

Use JavaScript

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
  <p id="random-text"></p>
  <button id="word-btn">Get Word</button>

  <script>
    var randomText = document.querySelector("#random-text")
    var randomWords = ["hello", "world", "goodbye"]
    var wordBtn = document.querySelector("#word-btn")

    wordBtn.addEventListener("click", function() {
      var randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * randomWords.length)
      randomText.textContent = randomWords[randomIndex]
     })
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```